# Managing process artifacts in a Mercurial release

Tags: version-control, mercurial, release-management

I am wondering what the best way might be to use Mercurial to create a release revision that includes artifacts that provide evidence of process execution.  For example, we'd like to attach system test results, check lists, release notes, etc. so that if we are audited by a customer we can easily show that we performed our process.  This is important to us due to the safety aspects of our product.

Our release management process will go something like the drawing below.  All developers are developing in local repos and periodically pushing to main.  Main is the latest and greatest but not necessarily safe for even internal engineering purposes outside of the dev team.

When we want to create a release for the customer or for other internal engineering departments, we start with a release candidate branch (e.g. RC1).  If any fixes are required, we commit to the RC branch.  Testing occurs on this branch.  When the RC is determined to be good, the changes are merged back to main.

We think that what we would like to do is merge into a Releases branch.  However, we have a chicken and an egg problem related to the artifacts: The artifacts that we would like include in the release revision contain, among other things, the hash for the revision.  This provides clear traceability that the testing and other process steps were performed on this precise revision.  But, to add these items, I need to create a new revision and I obviously can't know what the hash for that revision will be before I create it.  I am wondering if there is some way to "amend" a revision without changing the hash?

The only way to do this, that I can think of, would be, for example, in the drawing below, to create a revision RC2.3 that contains the necessary process artifacts but actually merge RC2.2 to Releases.

Then, of course, I have another problem and that is that the merge of RC2.2 into Releases will generate a new hash.  So, my artifacts are out of date again.  So the next question is whether there is some way to have the Release branch "point to" RC2.2.

BTW, we're open to changing this process if necessary.  Our reasons for using this methodology are:

- CI system is monitoring main and kicks off a series of builds and performs automated unit testing on each push.  There are frequent changes to main and we don't want people using it.
- Development can continue on main with no impact to the release.
- Any revision on the Releases branch kicks off a different set of tasks on our CI platform, including the creation of a distribution of a field flash utility and the required images (we're developing firmware).  This is how we provide releases to outside entities.

> ```
> Main         A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K--L---------M-------------N  
>                        \            /          \                     /  
> RC1                     RC1.0--RC1.1            \                   /  
>                          \                       \                 /  
> RC2                       \                        RC2.0--RC2.1--RC2.2  
>                            \                                       \   
>                             \                                       \  
> Releases                    ER1.0-----------------------------------PR1.0
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

> I am wondering if there is some way to "amend" a revision without changing the hash?

No, that's impossible by design. The changeset hash is a cryptographic checksum derived from the content of the commit — this is why the changeset hash uniquely identifies the content of all the files in the changeset.

The Mercurial wiki has a page with a [standard branch setup](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching). I'll describe how it works with pictures below.

What people normally do in your situation is to create a branch for release candidates like you suggest. If you're about to release version 2.0 of your firmware, then I would call the branch `2.x`. The commits on the branch are release candidates for your version 2.0:

```
Main      A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K--L---------M-------------N  
                 \                /
2.x               2.0-RC1--2.0-RC2
```

Bugfixes are committed on the branch as needed and merged back into Main regularly. You should always be able to merge the bugfixes back since they are by their nature bugfixes and stability improvements that you want to have on Main too. In other words, commit `I` above has the bugfixes in `2.0-RC2` plus the new features in `D` to `H`.

You can work on the release candidate branch as much as you want and keep fixing bugs:

```
Main      A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K--L-------M-------------N  
                 \            /                   /
2.x               2.0-RC1--2.0RC2 -- ... --2.0-RC8
```

All bugfixes are merged back since the rule is that you can only do fixes on the release candidate branch that are safe. Here you had 8 release candidates on the release branch.

When you like the status of the release candidate, you can tag it and run the more comprehensive tests on the revision you tagged. The output of a succesfull test is committed on the branch and you then tag *that* commit as the final released version:

```
Main      A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K--L-------M-----------N  
                 \            /                   /           /
2.x               2.0-RC1--2.0RC2 -- ... --2.0-RC8 -- T -- 2.0
```

Here `T` has the test output for `2.0-RC8` included. Commit `T` is the one you tag as version 2.0 of your software and the one you package and ship to your customers.

Should you need to create a version 2.1 with a bugfix to 2.0 (but no new features), then you continue with the same scheme:

```
Main      A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K--L-------M-----------N  
                 \            /                   /           /
2.x               2.0-RC1--2.0RC2 -- ... --2.0-RC8 -- T -- 2.0 -- 2.1-RC1
```

That is why I called the branch `2.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of mercurial seems a bit complicated with all those merges all over the place and will be painful to handle.
You are using the branches feature of mercurial, but seems to overlook 2 other important features:

1. Tags
2. Cherry Pick

I'll describe below our general usage of mercurial to highlight those features:

***Note that the following only applies to projects for which different versions need to be maintained over time.***

The main branch (called default in mercurial) is dedicated as you to the current development of the application.
Every time a developer complete the development/modification/update of a functionality, he/she pushes their change into default, which is then available to everybody and to our CI (jenkins) which will ensure nothing is broken.

When we reach a stage where a new version is about to be released a branch is created. In reference to your schema, the branch could be named MY_PRODUCT_1_0

Developers will continue to work on the default branch, and any time a commit need to be in the coming release, the related changeset will be copied to the MY_PRODUCT_1_0 branch via the command `hg graft REV_CHANGESET` (cherry pick) (note you can also copy from MY_PRODUCT_1_0 branch to default).

So you basically select which changesets from the default branch will make it to the current release, without having to merge the 2 branches.

***This requires developers to push clean and atomic changesets, which is how things should be done in mercurial in the first place.***

As your commits evolve in the MY_PRODUCT_1_0 you can tag it multiple times along the way as your schema from MY_PRODUCT_1_0_RC_1, MY_PRODUCT_1_0_RC_2,... 
When the final changeset is made on this branch you just need to tag it MY_PRODUCT_1_0_PR_1_0

You then get only 2 branches at first, default (the dev branch) and MY_PRODUCT_1_0 (your first release), and as time goes on when you need to release a new version of your product, you create a new branch MY_PRODUCT_2_0 and restart the cycle as described above.

With this approach you are sure that you only have the required changes in your releases, and not extra ones that you would get when merging branches.

I hope I was clear enought, if not let me know.